# How to build an existing Qt project in Visual Studio?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a visual C++ project that contains references to Qt libraries but I am unable to build it in Visual Studio. I installed Qt 5 sdk and plugin in VS 2012 and the initial sample Qt projects work fine, but not the older project  - it could be an issue related to the project being compatible to an older version of Qt - but I don't know how to solve the problem. The error keeps showing - "The system cannot find the path specified visual c++.  Moc'ing .. Uic'ing.."

The error says MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. The solution explorer contains some moc_xx.cpp files which are only references and are not present in the project directory. I removed them and tried rebuilding but it gives the same error

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: Added some. Not sure what more details I should add.

Comment: Update PATH variable in system settings

Answer (score 4):

QTDIR must be set prior to starting Visual Studio for the project to properly find the location of moc.exe and uic.exe.

The Qt Visual Studio Add-in will create custom build steps for .ui and header files whenever Qt files are added or modified. It is then Visual Studio that runs the custom build rules but these rules typically reference $(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe.

Comment: Yes I set the directory in Qtoptions -> Qtversions and new Qt projects are executing correctly.

Comment: What was the old project using before? There were many different ways that older versions of the qt-add/integration defined qt versions. One way to check is in the project file under <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties ..>

Comment: I don't know how to figure out the older qt version - the only reason I knew the project contained qt was that the solution explorer had some moc_xx.cpp files which are only references and are not present in the project directory. It's saying Error 1 error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.

Comment: moc_* files are files that are generated while building the project. You meta object compiler (moc) setup is not correct otherwise the files would be created on built.

Comment: Btw, I was saying that the environment variable, QTDIR needed to be set. This isn't set through the add-in guis in Visual Studio. I don't think this was cleared up from earlier comments. Why doesn't the add-in do this for you? You got me. I've dealt with this on a daily basis on a large team and this is usually the issue. Apologies if I am wrong.

Comment: Got it working. I redid all the steps, still not sure what the problem was. I reloaded the project, converted it to a Qt project and it was working. Something about the conversion was not working before.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the same problem recently with Visual Studio 2015 and Qt 5.7 and QtPackage.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar issue recently with an old VS project created years ago by a colleague.

The VS project was created using ***qmake***. It contains the ***absolute full path to the moc.exe***, of the machine where it was originally created. That is, of the PC of my colleague who left the team.

I do not have moc.exe at same location as he had it.
Therefore, the MOC step in build fails, with the error: ***the system cannot find the path specified***.

You could find what the path is, by raising build output verbosity to diagnostic for instance.

Hope it helps.